# Get value from Object, Object, Object item

Tags: javascript

I have built an array with PHP that contains some data. With "print json_encode($MyArray)" i transfer this array to a javascript function.

```
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "data.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
```

The transfered data i could access with **var s = data.location**. But how could i get the value from e.g. Person 2 and there the age ?

This is not working: **var x = data.person.2.age;**

Here is a example from the console.log window.

```
Object
    Name: ""
    Disciption: ""
    location: ""
    person: Object
        1: Object
            name: ""
            age: ""
        2: Object
            name: ""
            age: ""
```

Comment: I can only guess that `data.person` is an array - in this case try this: `data.person[1].age` (for second person - array indexes starting from zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `person` is an array, so you need to specify index to access the age.
`var x = data.person[0].age;` 
and
`var x = data.person[1].age;`

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = data.person.2.age;
```

should be

```
var x = data.person[2].age;
```